# Jqplot tooltip values incorrect when chart has two lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have a jqplot chart that has two lines. I'm using tooltipContentEditor to modify the text displayed in the tooltip. Prior to adding the second line, the tooltips displayed the values fine. Now that I have added another line, the tooltips always show the data for the second line (thus incorrectly for the first). How do I have the correct values displayed?

Blue line tooltip shows yellow line value:
[image: JQPLOT]

Chart initialization (tooltipContentEditor function inside):

```
$.jqplot('mychart', [coords, paidCoords], {
        //title:'Sales for ' + name,
        animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
        axesDefaults: {
            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
        },

        axes:{
            xaxis:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                tickInterval: tickInterval,
                tickOptions: { formatString: formatString, angle: -30 }
            },
            yaxis:{
                min:0
            }
        },

        highlighter: {
            show: true,
            sizeAdjust: 7.5,
            tooltipContentEditor: function(str, pointIndex, index, plot){
                        console.log('logging in tooltipeditor');
                        console.log(str);
                        console.log(pointIndex);
                        console.log(index);
                        console.log(plot);
                        var splitted = plot._plotData[1][index];
                        var x = splitted[0];
                        var y = splitted[1];

                        x = new Date(x);
                        x = x.toString(); 
                        return x + "<br/>$" + y;
            }
        },
        cursor:{ 
            show: true,
            zoom:true, 
            showTooltip:false
          } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I figured it out! In the tooltipContentEditor function I needed to do this:

```
var splitted = str.split(",");
```

Instead of this:

```
var splitted = plot._plotData[1][index];
```

Comment: Actually, does anyone know how to get the tooltip to show the original data? The str is showing the formatted date.